# How to manage same slug posts suffix method?

Tags: slug

```php
domain.tld/post-name   |   post_id = 5
```

and

```php
domain.tld/post-name-2 |   post_id = 77
```

The above scenario is the solution brought by wordPress.
Let's complicate this a bit and add it as a prefix for example or timestamp etc. If we want to add something, how do we do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Developers can use the following filter:

```php
/**
     * Filters the post slug before it is generated to be unique.
     *
     * Returning a non-null value will short-circuit the
     * unique slug generation, returning the passed value instead.
     *
     * @since 5.1.0
     *
     * @param string|null $override_slug Short-circuit return value.
     * @param string      $slug          The desired slug (post_name).
     * @param int         $post_ID       Post ID.
     * @param string      $post_status   The post status.
     * @param string      $post_type     Post type.
     * @param int         $post_parent   Post parent ID.
     */
    $override_slug = apply_filters( 'pre_wp_unique_post_slug', null, $slug, $post_ID, $post_status, $post_type, $post_parent );
```

It is then the programmer's responsibility to ensure uniqueness of the slug.